# UI is not update,while list & model is updated Gext Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-getx

Hlo friendsz
I'm working with observable list.affing data to the list using the model object. list and model values updating but UI where getting data is not updated until dont do hot relaod.ui in Obs widget also.update() and refresh() functions also not working.

Code Pictures are here.
https://github.com/Qurat-ul-ainn/GwtxIssues/commit/0c53507bf999870fa36cdbb2cb73e348feeb17f6

Comment: can you include the code so far?>

Comment: I'm new.Don't know how to use stackoverflow tired to attach code pics but not allowed

Comment: ahh can u edit your question the image is no in der

Comment: getting notification..Image is not allowed

Comment: https://github.com/Qurat-ul-ainn/GwtxIssues/commit/0c53507bf999870fa36cdbb2cb73e348feeb17f6   code Screenshorts are here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetBuilder for listView updation , Obx will mostly works for variable updations

Wrap you listview with GetBuilder

```
GetBuilder<YourController>(
      builder: (_) => ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

 })   );
```

and use

```
Get.find<YourController>.update();
```

or

```
update();
```

to update the ui

Comment: Where to use it. I am using it in function but not getting any result.

Comment: can you show your code please

Comment: https://github.com/Qurat-ul-ainn/GwtxIssues/commit/0c53507bf999870fa36cdbb2cb73e348feeb17f6

Comment: ahh he meant to put it here as per you code so far

Comment: on your first image inside the expanded widget wrap the lisview builder with GetBuilder like the above , and on the second image function on the last line call the Get.find<YourController>.update();

Comment: okayy...then mark it as accepted :)